# Two definitions of locally compact space

Tags: general-topology

I have seen two definitions of locally compact topological space

- A topological space $(X,\mathcal{F})$ is said to be locally compact if for every $x\in X$, there exists a compact set that contains an open neighborhood of $x$.
- A topological space $(X,\mathcal{F})$ is said to be locally compact if for every $x\in X$, there exists an open neighborhood of $x$ whose closure is compact.

Are these two definitions equivalent? It's clear that the second implies the first, but I don't see why the first implies the second. Suppose that $U $ is an open neighborhood of $x$ with $x\in U\subset K$, here $K$ is a compact set. Since compact sets may not be closed in a non-Hasudorff topological space, the closure of $U$ may not be contained $K$, so we can't say the closure of $U$ is compact.

Comment: just take the closure of the open neighborhood from the first. A closed subset of a compact set is always compact.

Comment: @ForeverMozart If $U\subset C$, and $C$ is compact, then without the Hausdorff condition that is no reason that we will have $\overline{U} \subset C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a line with infinitely many origins, i.e. the space obtained by gluing together infinitely many copies of $\mathbb{R}$ along the open subset $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Each point of $X$ has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, so $X$ satisfies definition 1.  But the closure of any neighborhood of one of the origins cannot be compact, since it contains an infinite discrete set as a closed subspace, so $X$ does not satisfy definition 2.

We could also glue together infinitely many copies of the Sierpinski space for a similar counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I meet the same question in the definition of relatively compact set. (i) A set is relatively compact if it is contained in a compact set. (ii) A set is relatively if its closure is compact. These two definitions are also not equivalent?

Comment: @XiangYu Correct.  The same example works, and for the same reason: any one of the origins has a compact neighborhood (e.g. the corresponding $[-1,1]$), but the closure of any such neighborhood must include all the origins, hence not be compact.  So this neighborhood is relatively compact in the first sense, but not the second.