# Two different definitions of locally compact spaces

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

There are two different definitions of locally compact spaces.

1.A topological space $(X,T)$ is said to be locally compact if for every $x\in X$, there exists an open neighborhood of $x$  whose closure is compact.

2.A topological space $(X,T)$ is said to be locally compact if every point in $X$ has a compact neighborhood.

Are they equivalent?  It is obvious that 1 implies 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in the case the space is Hausdorff (thanks to David Hartley for pointing out that [it's not true in the non-Hausdorff case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1574613/730238)). By definition, a neighbourhood has to contain an open neighbourhood. Therefore, a compact neighbourhood $K$ of a point $x$ contains an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ whose closure, being a closed subset of a compact space $K$, is compact.

Comment: No. The closure of U is not necessarily within K, if we don't assume Hausdorff. This question is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574608/two-definitions-of-locally-compact-space?rq=1 , where the answer gives a counter-example.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I indeed missed the non-Hausdorff case. Thank you.

Comment: So what is the precise definition of locally compact spaces?

Comment: As far as I understand, in the non-Hausdorff case one usually prefers the second one. If one assumes Hausdorff (which is reasonable in the overwhelming majority of applications), then both are equivalent.